# Install anti virus in Ubuntu14

Tags: antivirus

I installed latest Ubuntu 14 64 bit

kindly suggest me an anti-virus to install compatible with Ubuntu 14

please also explain the steps to install it

Comment: the only virus protection you need on Ubuntu are those for Windows viruses if you install windows software. There are no (known) viruses for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The predominant antivirus for Linux based systems is called clamav.

You install it with

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

However, that does not set up a graphical interface for it, nor does it enable scheduled or on-demand scanning - you have to scan manually via the command-line.

Therefore, there are a variety of other tools you can use to extend the functionality of clamav.

For starters, you may want to try clamtk which is a graphical frontend:

```
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```